# Reclass raster with range input in Model Builder (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, modelbuilder, reclassify

I would like to use the QGIS model builder to preform reclassifications on several rasters. In QGIS I use `r.reclass` to do the reclassification by a given range (f.e.: 100 thru 150 = 1)

In Model Builder I'm not able to set the range-input (Sunshine duration range in the screenshot) to the `r.reclass` rule. As you can see in the screenshot. Of course, `r.reclass` is expecting a rule like "100 thru 150 = 1".

[image]

How could I do a reclassification by a range input on a raster using the model builder?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly your problem, the solution is to build a model using the input Expression instead of Range.

[image]

Using this method, running the Model you will have the possibility to change the expression/range. 
[image]